# Can not activate a virtual environment in emacs, but can through the usual shell

Tags: python, term, ubuntu, virtualenv

I created a virtual environment that I can activate used a command line from Terminal (Ubuntu):

```
source/bin activate
```

I did what follows to achieve the same on emacs:

<kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>!</kbd> then `source/bin activate` then <kbd>RET</kbd>

But then I guess the virtual environment is not activated and I am getting this error message:

> /bin/bash: source/bin: No such file or directory

What am I missing?

**EDIT 1:**

It seems I have to use a package like [`auto-virtualenv`](https://github.com/marcwebbie/auto-virtualenv); and for that I have to tell Emacs to use the MELPA repository. So following the [documentation](https://melpa.org/#/getting-started).
I restarted Emacs but still can not install that package with it (<kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>!</kbd> `package-install` <kbd>RET</kbd> `auto-virtualenv`<kbd>RET</kbd> )

**EDIT 2:**

Installing the virtual environment `auto-virtualenv` is done thanks to [wvxvw](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/40701/can-not-activate-a-virtual-environment-in-emacs-but-can-through-the-usual-shell#comment63774_40701)'s comment below. So I am supposed to get rid of the error I mentioned above, but no, it is still there.

**EDIT 3:**

When I run <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>!</kbd> then `pwd` I get this:

```
/home/h4ck3r/development/app
```

Then I type <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>!</kbd>  and `source/bin activate`, I get this error message:

> /bash: source/bin: No such file or directory

Comment: Several things in play here: your current directory at the point where you invoke this command isn't set to the parent directory of `source/bin`, activating virtual environment like this won't have the desired effect, there's a package for that, and the command is `M-x pyvenv-activate` iirc. I think, these days it is packaged with Elpy: https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy

Comment: I am on the right directory, but as you said I need to install a package. I am trying to use [auto-virtualenv](https://github.com/marcwebbie/auto-virtualenv) but I am having difficulty to configure the `.emacs` file to use MELPA packages as described [here](https://melpa.org/#/getting-started)

Comment: I think I'm actually using `pyvenv.el`, as for your setup: it looks standard. Can you try instead `M-x list-packages`, then find the package you want to install, then press `i` on it, then `x`?

Comment: Your comment solved the problem related to installing the virtual environment package. So thank you very much. I just do not understand why I still am getting the same error mentioned in my question when I run `source/bin activate`

Comment: Try `M-! pwd` to see what bash sees as its current directory, that will probably explain why it cannot find `source/bin`.

Comment: That outputs the directory which is the virtual environment I created and in which I am running `source/bin activate`. Note that I previously created that virtual environment with Ubuntu Terminal, not from Emacs, do you think that could be the origin of the problem?

Comment: Ah, I think I understand now. If you spell it exactly like you did, i.e. without `./` prefix, Bash will look for this directory on the `PATH` not, in the current directory.

Comment: Please consider (1) cleaning up the question, to incorporate your various successive edits and perhaps some info from the comments and (2) posting an answer, if an answer came out of the comments. You can accept your own answer. Be aware that comments can be deleted anytime - it is Q's and A's where the ultimatately useful info belongs.

Comment: I am trying to understand the last comment of wxvw. I did not solve this yet. @Drew

Comment: What I meant was that when you do `M-! bin/source activate` it ultimately translates into `bash bin/source activate`, but what you need is `bash ./bin/source activate` otherwise Bash will not look for your script in `PWD`.

Comment: I aö getting a different error: `bash: bin/source: No such file or directory`. Thank you @wvxvw

Comment: Oh, sorry, that was a typo on my part! `M-! ./source/bin activate`.

Comment: I tried that before, and retried now but getting: `/bin/bash: ./source/bin: No such file or directory `. Thank you @wvxvw

Comment: Hm... I don't really know what to tell you. That works for me, provided `$PWD/source/bin` is an executable script and it accepts `activate` as an argument. Though, typically, `activate` is the name of a script.  Are you sure it's not `./source/bin/activate`?

Comment: Sorry for misleading you but after spending quite a long time reading the documentation, I found there is nothing wrong with the logic you shared with me. I just mislead you to copy/paste my `source/bin activate` instead of `source bin/activate`. Regarding your patience and efforts, you can summarize your comments as an answer which I will gladly accept and upvote. Thank you very much @wvxvw

Answer (score 1):

I think `source/bin` is not an executable.

Maybe the good command is:

`. $PATH_TO_VIRTUALENV/bin/activate` or
`source $PATH_TO_VIRTUALENV/bin/activate`